# Getters involving external data in Vue.js + Vuex

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, vuex

I am developing a Vue+Vuex based app running on Electron.
I hold a directory path as part of the state, signifying the current working directory for the user. In the app, I have a component in which I want to display all the files in the working directory. However, those change over time (the app / user can delete them, create new files, rename file etc...).

The way I originally structured it was to have a getter, which given the current working directory from the state, would fetch the file list. However, as the working directory didn't change, the getter (which only depends on it) wasn't called again.

I don't want to gold the file list in the state, as I don't want to have to update it + the actual file on the machine for every action taken.

I lathered it right now by having a "refresh" action that deletes and resets the working directory in the state, triggering a call to the getter. However, having to call it whenever I suspect something happened to a file is a little tedious.

What is the recommended solution here?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher ?

Comment: Thanks @RoyJ. Where would you normally place such watchers? within the component?

Comment: Within the component sounds good.